# Failed to load container mount 022183...: mount does not exist

Tags: docker

When I start docker:

```
service docker start
```

Shows this log:

```
Sep 15 02:05:16 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[13274]: time="2019-09-15T02:05:16.969535655+08:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Sep 15 02:05:16 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[13274]: time="2019-09-15T02:05:16.970807372+08:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Sep 15 02:05:16 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[13274]: time="2019-09-15T02:05:16.972484550+08:00" level=error msg="Failed to load container mount 022183ecc93800ee6af20bfa8a59ec3746568c73abbea29e3d305c46b468990c: mount does not exist"
Sep 15 02:05:16 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[13274]: time="2019-09-15T02:05:16.972792385+08:00" level=error msg="Failed to load container mount 05073c615ef179888e689414348f026116a206987ae4e66cff04fa85435e1e70: mount does not exist"
Sep 15 02:05:16 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[13274]: time="2019-09-15T02:05:16.973235355+08:00" level=error msg="Failed to load container mount 0857413708fdc210726d664b3c312fc65ff40448db177d9d2af545a13f91e48c: mount does not exist"
Sep 15 02:05:16 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[13274]: time="2019-09-15T02:05:16.973572688+08:00" level=error msg="Failed to load container mount 117c3e16388063b1741fb584f10bb2f7e09508c844b661e3cb628a836094f011: mount does not exist"
Sep 15 02:05:16 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[13274]: time="2019-09-15T02:05:16.973619897+08:00" level=error msg="Failed to load container 16831d8345c6ade3f96544a2bd95020841933480b4a9c96ae5d5f36a17eb310e: open /var/lib/docker/containers/16831d8345c6ade3f96544a2bd95020841933480b4a9c96ae5d5f36a17eb310e/config.v2.json: no such file or directory"
Sep 15 02:05:17 iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z dockerd[13274]: time="2019-09-15T02:05:17.167060906+08:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
```

docker info shows root path:

```
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
```

and container shows:

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t9Z containers]# ls
022183ecc93800ee6af20bfa8a59ec3746568c73abbea29e3d305c46b468990c  117c3e16388063b1741fb584f10bb2f7e09508c844b661e3cb628a836094f011
05073c615ef179888e689414348f026116a206987ae4e66cff04fa85435e1e70  16831d8345c6ade3f96544a2bd95020841933480b4a9c96ae5d5f36a17eb310e
0857413708fdc210726d664b3c312fc65ff40448db177d9d2af545a13f91e48c
```

why the docker still do not find container?

Comment: I am also facing this issue

Comment: I solved this by restore docker folder,I backup the folder before operate,maybe help you.

Comment: Please share the solution with me

Comment: I did not solved it,I solved it by restore from the backup folder.Have you back up the docker folder?@Bharath_Raja

Comment: Is there any default location for the docker backup folder?

Comment: No,I am backup by myself,the docker did not backup anything by default.

Comment: I had no backup, but after removing /var/lib/docker I could start the systemd docker again and run docker-compose (installed the containers automatically).   BTW: The docker problem occured after running apt upgrade.